# Salesforce Java rest api json structure for object creation

Tags: java, json, rest, salesforce

I am trying to set up REST API integration for custom java application with Salesforce. I have followed the tutorials/resources namely-

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/machine-machine-salesforce-integrations-java-rest-soap.html

http://www.asagarwal.com/step-by-step-guide-to-get-started-with-salesforce-rest-api-using-java/

These work perfectly fine. My question deals with creating/updating Salesforce object via REST api. The particular code snippet to construct the respective object to create is-|

```
        //create the JSON object containing the new lead details.
        JSONObject lead = new JSONObject();
        lead.put("FirstName", "REST API");
        lead.put("LastName", "Lead");
        lead.put("Company", "asagarwal.com");
```

And then there is the part to construct this http request which is fairly usual-

```
          //Construct the objects needed for the request
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader(oauthHeader);
        httpPost.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
        // The message we are going to post
        StringEntity body = new StringEntity(lead.toString(1));
        body.setContentType(&quot;application/json&quot;);
        httpPost.setEntity(body);
```

Constructing a json object in this fashion seems to me like it would be a maintenance issue. This involves right now having to go through the entire fields list of an object which could be 100s, and getting their field name. This seems really tedious. Is there a way where we can get the object structure of the particular Salesforce object in java and then perhaps I can use external libraries like `Jackson` and its annotations to serialize the object into json instead of manually having to construct this json object? I have tried to look for this online but the only way currently possible is to actually get the field names and construct a java bean myself and have that serialized to json. Any cleaner way to do this perhaps using any of Salesforce' capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the flexibility to setup a REST service in an Apex class that you could pass an object type to as a String?

You could write a web service that returns the JSON of an sObject by using JSON.serialize() on the SF side and returning it based on what was passed into the service.